# Getting a message "Cannot find module 'web3' " even though I have installed Web3

Tags: javascript, web3js

I was trying to run this command on my Mac Terminal, but I keep getting this feedback while I try to run it. I tried to follow the suggestions shared by the community, but could not go past this step.

[image]

Any suggestions around how to navigate this?

Comment: You wrote "even though I've installed Web3" - how? I see you being in an (invalid) `node_modules` directory inside of your home directly, and in your home directory. Both are not a project directory, or at least shouldn't be. Where did you put your project, and how did you install `web3`? Does `npm ls web3` show it installed (executed from your project directory)?

Comment: Hey, thanks for highlighting the above. Let me share these details.

Answer (score 0):

Do try doing this:
run `npm i web3`

Drop into the repl like:
`node`
`>>` `const Web3 = require('web3')`
`Web3. (press tab to see the web3 api)`

This installs web3 in the current path, inside a node_modules folder making it usable inside the `node repl`
See the attached screenshot. node_modules shouldn't be a bother. I delete them once I'm done with the use.[image]
[image: check if web3 is installed]

[image: install web3]

[image: Web3, type Web3. then to see all the functions exposed by Web3]